# How to skip the certificate verification for the openshift webhook in bitbucket?

Tags: ssl, bitbucket, openshift, openshift-origin, okd

I have created a webhook for a project which uses bitbucket, for which certificate verification needs to be skipped while adding the webhook URL in the bitbucket, since the openshift is using a self-signed certificate.

The following is the openshift webhook url for the build triger:

```
https://<openshift_api_host:port>/oapi/v1/namespaces/<namespace>/buildconfigs/<name>/webhooks/<secret>/bitbucket
```

Note: The above URL works only with HTTPS and does not work with HTTP.

I have referred https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/manage-webhooks-735643732.html, which is for a cloud version of bitbucketand that has a checkbox to skip the certificate verification, I'm using bitbucket-6.8.1 which does not have this checkbox option. Because of this, the test connection button in bitbucket webhooks is failing with error  "javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem". So how can I configure bitbucket to skip the SSL certificate verification? Otherwise, is there any workaround that could be done from openshift or bitbucket?

Bitbucket version: 6.8.1

Openshift/okd version: 3.11

Comment: What I did was to place a valid SSL certificate on my Router and on my Console. You can get Let's Encrypt certificates so you can skip this issue.

Comment: I have tried Lets encrypt  to generated a certificate , but it fails since i dont have a public domain name. Will it work if i use nip.io to set the hostname or any other work arounds?

Comment: Some domain vendors sells domains for lest than 1 USD and they offer free DNS hosting. Also I found an [answer for your issue](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Create-a-webhook-in-Bitbucket-Server-and-skip-certificate/qaq-p/670134) where they ask the customer to use port 80 instead of port 443. You can do that in Openshift so maybe this is another option for you.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, but as i mentioned a note in the question, my openshift works with https(443) only.

Comment: Well, buy a domain and issue a certificate